# reledpar: apply formatting to right-side paragraphs

Tags: formatting, reledmac, reledpar

In reledpar I'm trying to format all right-side paragraphs with italicized text all at once, without enclosing every paragraph in `\textit{}`. Is this possible? The closest I've come is with `\AtStartEveryPstart`, except that I can't see how to make that apply to right-side paragraphs and not the left side also.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\AtStartEveryPstart{\itshape} % affects the left and right side
\begin{document}
  \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart      
        The first left paragraph.
      \pend
      \pstart
        The second left paragraph.
      \pend
      \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart
        The first right paragraph.
      \pend
      \pstart
        The second right paragraph.
      \pend
      \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
  \end{pages}
  \Pages
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use the boolean test `\ifledRcol`
2. You should not use use `\itshape`, but should prefer `\emph`, which allow, in you have a `\emph` inside your paragraph to switch-back to roman font
3. As `\emph` need argument, you must use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` to replace brackets
4. You must use the `\egroup` on `\AtEndEveryPend`, and the `\bgroup` on `\AtStartEveryPstart`, in order to enclose the paragraph as an argument of `\emph`.

So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\AtStartEveryPstart{\ifledRcol\emph\bgroup\fi} % affects right side
\AtEndEveryPend{\ifledRcol\egroup\fi} % affects  right side
\begin{document}
  \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart
      The \emph{first} left paragraph.
      \pend
      \pstart
      The \emph{second} left paragraph.
      \pend
      \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart
      The \emph{first} right paragraph.
      \pend
      \pstart
      The \emph{second} right paragraph.
      \pend
      \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
  \end{pages}
  \Pages
\end{document}
```